# dropping an image with win32com (MS WORD)

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I am trying to create a series of name badges and rather than doing it all by hand I'm trying to do it via python. I am using the win32com.client approach to create a table in msword to hold each name badge however the images I am inserting into each cell are pushed up against the top of the cell whereas I want them moved down a bit (Image is oversized I know but that can be dealt with later).

[image: name badge]

As you can see the image is write against the top of the border, I want it pushing down, I have tried adding newlines before (demonstrated below) but this seems to have had no effect. This is my loop for generating the badges.

```
for i in range(10):
    cell_col = i % cols + 1
    cell_row = i / cols + 1

    cell_range = table.Cell(cell_row, cell_col).Range

    cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    cell_range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 3
    table.Cell(cell_row, cell_col).Range.InsertBefore('\n')
    cell_range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), filename))
    table.Cell(cell_row, cell_col).Range.InsertAfter('\n'+hold[i])
    table.Cell(cell_row, cell_col).Height = 150
    table.Cell(cell_row, cell_col).Width = 250
```